# A uniformly bounded local martingale is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I was trying to prove that a uniformly bounded local martingale is a martingale.

Clearly a bounded local martingale is integrable.

I know how to show that a lower bounded local martingale is a supermartingale using Fatous's Lemma but somehow I cannot show that a uniformly bounded local martingale is a sub-martingale. Any hints on how could I show that?

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformly bounded"?

Comment: @saz . A stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t \in I}$ is said to be uniformly bounded if $\exists K >0 $ such that $|X_t| \leq K \forall t \in I$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a uniformly bounded local martingale. Then there exists a sequence of stopping times $(\tau_k)_k$ such that $\tau_k \uparrow \infty$ and $(M_{t \wedge \tau_k})_t$ is a martingale for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge \tau_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = M_{s \wedge \tau_k}$$

for all $ s\leq t$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $M$ is uniformly bounded, it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that

$$\begin{align*} M_s &= \lim_{k \to \infty} M_{s \wedge \tau_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge \tau_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s). \end{align*}$$ This shows that $M$ is a martingale.

Comment: I suppose you have used the following result:  If you have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ s.t. $|X_n|\leq f$ for some $f \in L^1$ and $X_n$ converge to X almost surely, then the conditional expectations of $X_n$ to some subsigma-algebra converge almost surely to the conditional expectaion of $X$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Emilian Yes, that's correct.