# l1-bounded local martingale is uniformly integrable martingale

Tags: martingales, stopping-times, localization, uniform-integrability, local-martingales

Let $M$ be a cadlag local martingale, i.e. there exists a sequence of stopping times $\{ \tau_k\} $ such that $\tau_k \to \infty$ and $M^{\tau_k}$ is a u.i. martingale for all $k$. Let $M_t$ be also $L_1$-bounded, i.e. $E ( \sup_{t\geq0 }|M_t|) < \infty$. Prove that $M$ is then a u.i. martingale.

First of all, I am asking myself whether this is true when we only have cadlag paths and no continuity (see below). But I especially have difficulties proving the uniform integrability. Any ideas?

Here: [A uniformly bounded local martingale is a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316240/a-uniformly-bounded-local-martingale-is-a-martingale) is a prove for the martingale property but I guess continuity is needed?

Comment: actually you have the equivalence between the statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question, which you linked, does not assume continuity of sample paths. The proof only uses $M_{s \wedge \tau_k}(\omega) = M_s(\omega)$ for $k=k(\omega,s)$ sufficiently large (...which has nothing to do with continuity but follows from $\tau_k \uparrow \infty$). Consequently, you can use the reasoning from the linked question to prove the martingale property.

The uniform integrability of $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ follows from the following lemma:

> Let $Y \geq 0$ be an integrable random variable and $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of random variables with $|X_i| \leq Y$ for all $i \in I$. Then $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is uniformly integrable.

Apply this for $Y:=\sup_{t \geq 0} |M_t|$ and $X_t := M_t$.

Comment: I just noticed that I do not only have $L_1$-boundedness but that $E (\sup_{t\geq 0} |M_t | ) < \infty$ which is stronger... Then it is, like you wrote, easy. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixT. Yes... therefore the title of your question is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @FelixP. I am sorry but is it not L1 bouded to be $E [\sup | M_t | ] \leq \infty$ ? and how do you know that $ E [\sup | M_t | ] \implies \sup | M_t | $? It seems to me that the proof you gave relies on this statement.